# Select from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a database table that I'm trying to select from. THe table looks like this:

```
ID           | Rule       | RuleName | RuleID
 (autonumber)| (xmlstring)| FakeName | a984kjg9

(autonumber) |(xmlstring) |FakeName1 |a4844asdf
```

You get the picture....ok, so my problem is that I know nothing of C#.

I have this so far.

```
DataTable dtWebRules = new DataTable();
          dtWebRules = LoadRuleXmlFromDB(dtWebRules);
```

and *I am trying to grab the (xmlstring) from the RULE column in the DB table and set it to string xmlstring *

So far, I have this, but i know it's wrong.

```
 int dtRow = 0;
  foreach (DataRow row in dtWebRules.Row)
  {
 string xmlstring = dtWebRules.Select("Rule").ToString();
 dtRow = dtRow + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps a C# course is in order.

Comment: what is the dtRow for? You are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var xmlRulesList = dtWebRules.Rows.Select(x => x["Rule"].ToString()).ToList();
```

or for something that performs better:

```
 var xmlRules = dtWebRules.Rows.Select(x => x["Rule"].ToString());

 foreach(string rule in xmlRules)
 {
     // do fun stuff with each rule
 }
```

the second will perform better because the list does not need to be created before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtWebRules.Row)
{
   string xmlstring = row["Rule"].ToString();
}
```